# How do i compare a single number with different numbers in another array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, compare

I have an id(example:2) and i have a list with different id's(example:1, 2, 3, 4, 5). 
I want that the id 2 is checked in the list with 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 and if its equal (both id's are the same as in 2 = 2). But in my code it only checks the first line. So because the other array starts with a 1 instead of a 2 cant my code find the connect and doesnt do anything. like this:

```
        2 = 1 , false
(here it stops) = 2,  false
(here it stops) = 3,  false
(here it stops) = 4,  false
```

and i want this :

```
        2 = 1 , false
        2 = 2 , true -> execute a code
        2 = 3 , false
        2 = 4 , false
```

can anyone help me out here ? 
This is my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) {

    if (ascalda[i].address_email.indexOf(emailArray[i].email_id) >= 0) {
        emaill.push(emailArray[i].email_title);
    }
```

Arrays:

```
ascalda: 

{"address_id":"1",
"address_street":"Vlietstraat",
"address_postalcode":"4536 DG",
"address_housenr":"1",
"address_city":"Terneuzen",
"address_country":"Nederland",
"address_email":"1",
"address_telnr":"1"};





emailArray:
 [
 {email_id: '2', email_title: 'RocWebmail@roc.nl', email_type: '9'},
 {email_id: '1', email_title: 'ScaldaWebmail@scalda.nl', email_type: '8'}
 ];
```

I use titanium as program.
Thanks in advance!!

My console log :

```
[INFO][ActivityManager(   62)] Starting: Intent { cmp=com.Innovisionsolutions.com/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity (has extras) } from pid 425
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  ["1"]
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  [{"address_id":"1","address_street":"Vlietstraat","address_postalcode":"4536 DG","address_housenr":"1","address_city":"Terneuzen","address_country":"Nederland","address_email":"1","address_telnr":"1"}]
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  1
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  undefined
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  [{"address_id":"1","address_street":"Vlietstraat","address_postalcode":"4536 DG","address_housenr":"1","address_city":"Terneuzen","address_country":"Nederland","address_email":"1","address_telnr":"1"}]
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  [{"email_id":"2","email_title":"RocWebmail@roc.nl","email_type":"9"},{"email_id":"1","email_title":"ScaldaWebmail@scalda.nl","email_type":"8"}]
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  1
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  ["ScaldaWebmail@scalda.nl"]
[INFO][TiAPI   (  425)]  ["623232323"]
[INFO][ActivityManager(   62)] Displayed com.Innovisionsolutions.com/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity: +1s248ms
```

Comment: are you sure your ascalada is correct?

Comment: @Mritunjay Yeah its correct. :/

Comment: @VickyGonsalves Whats a jsfiddle :P?

Comment: Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @VickyGonsalves http://jsfiddle.net/Qh3WL/ I dont think this will work though, the code is based for an android app :P

Comment: yeah it won't work as its Titanium based code..but if you ignore titanium code, it should work

Comment: Your ascalda is an object(I think it is not valid,It shows error in your input) And emailArray is an array. But you get address_email and email_id as array, see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp try again :)

Comment: @saravanakumar updated my console in the thread :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this

```
    for (var j = 0; i < ascalda.length; j++) {
     for (var i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) {
        if (ascalda[j].address_email == emailArray[i].email_id) {
            emaill.push(emailArray[i].email_title);
        } 
     }
    }
```

Since you are using same string( "1","2"..) for both values.

Comment: Doesnt work, but if i replace the [i] with [0] in ascalda[i].address_email
 it works, the problem is then that it only works if ascalda.address_email has 1 number, and it has multiple :P